# What is context in makeNode(in: Context) vapor 3?

Tags: swift, vapor

Using Vapor for return model to node :

```
 func indexView(request: Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable
    {
        let acro = try Acronym.makeQuery().sort(Acronym.idKey, .ascending)

        return try acro.all().makeNode(in: <#T##Context?#>)
    }
```

It always return error and don't know how to fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contexts are used generally to pass current-use information around inside Vapor. The Vapor 3 documentation does not appear to contain detailed information (yet), but see https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/node/getting-started/ for Vapor 2. I have never found a need for them in makeNode, so putting:

```
return try acro.all().makeNode(in:nil)
```

should make it work.

Comment: Node doesn't exist in Vapor 3

Answer (score 1):

Node has been phased out in Vapor3. There's no need for it since it relies in Swift's native data types+protocols. In this case, Vapor 3 uses Content to work with JSON. (Content conforms to Codable by default)

e.g.

```swift
final class Person: Content, MySQLModel, Migration {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String

    init(id: Int? = nil, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

}

func person(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Person> {
    return Person(name: "Mark")
}

router.get("test") { req -> Future<[Person]> in
    return try Person.query(on: req).sort(\.id, .ascending).all()
}
```

Excerpt from the docs:

> In Vapor 3, all content types (JSON, protobuf, URLEncodedForm, Multipart, etc) are treated the same. All you need to parse and serialize content is a Codable class or struct.